# Lightweight incremental classification of 1 dimensional data in java

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification

I have a set of pairs of observations (value, class). Values are natural numbers. There are only two classes. I expect that it is quite easy to separate the classes at a single decision point, e.g., class A if value < 10, class B if value >= 10. The only difficulty is that there is some overlap between classes and values near the decision boundary.

Is there a fast and lightweight way to update observations and classify a new data point in Java for this problem? Ideally something like:

```
classifier.addObservation(observation);
classifier.classify(value);
```

A solution would be a demonstration of a Java package for this and a  justification of your choice of algorithm.

Comment: If all observations are independent of each other and there is only one dimensional data, there is no way to classify values that lie on the overlap region.

Comment: Why is that? Wouldn't the decision boundary just be somewhere between the overlap? As there is a definition of distance wouldn't knn suffice?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but consider the following cases:
[1, A]
[2, A]
[5, A]
[11, A]
[9, B]
[12, B]
[15, B]
[20, B]

How would you classify 10?

Comment: One option would be to find the centre of mass of the A and B distributions and assign 10 the label of the closest centre.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood earlier. For some reason I thought that you wanted a way to classify those points in the center with 100% accuracy. The method you suggested will work. To improve accuracy you could also isolate the overlapping zone, calculate the ratio of points in that zone and weigh the results accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I ended up using [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/documentation.html). In particular I used a Naive Bayes classifier. Their data structures are a little esoteric but it works and it is fast.

```
package agent.agenttype.ijcai;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.SparseInstance;

public class Example {

     public static enum ClassLabel {A, B};

     Instances trainingSet;
     FastVector att = new FastVector(2);
     FastVector cl = new FastVector(2);

     public Example(){
         //Add class labels
         cl.addElement(ClassLabel.values()[0].name());
         cl.addElement(ClassLabel.values()[1].name());
         //set the name of our value attribute
         Attribute Attribute1 = new Attribute("Value"); 
         //set the name of our class label atrribute
         Attribute ClassAttribute = new Attribute("Label", cl);      
         att.addElement(Attribute1);
         att.addElement(ClassAttribute);    
         //create training set that uses our attributes to interpret instances
         trainingSet = new Instances("TrainingSet", att, 2);
         trainingSet.setClassIndex(1);//tell our training set that index 2 of instances is the class label
     }

    public void addObservationToEdge(int value, ClassLabel classLabel){
            Instance instance = new SparseInstance(2);
            instance.setValue((Attribute)att.elementAt(0), value); //set value
            instance.setValue((Attribute)att.elementAt(1), classLabel.name());//set our
            trainingSet.add(instance);
    }

    public ClassLabel classifyValue( int value) throws Exception{

         Instance instanceForClassification = new SparseInstance(1);
         instanceForClassification.setValue((Attribute)att.elementAt(0), value);
         instanceForClassification.setDataset(trainingSet);//make instance inherit attribute labels from training set

         Classifier cModel = (Classifier)new NaiveBayes();//create naive bayes classifier
         cModel.buildClassifier(trainingSet);

         int labelNumber = (int) cModel.classifyInstance(instanceForClassification);
         return ClassLabel.values()[labelNumber];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Example example = new Example();
        example.addObservationToEdge(1, ClassLabel.A);
        example.addObservationToEdge(2, ClassLabel.A);
        example.addObservationToEdge(5, ClassLabel.A);
        example.addObservationToEdge(11, ClassLabel.A);
        example.addObservationToEdge(9, ClassLabel.B);
        example.addObservationToEdge(12, ClassLabel.B);
        example.addObservationToEdge(15, ClassLabel.B);
        example.addObservationToEdge(20, ClassLabel.B);

        try {
        //print classification results
        for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
            System.out.println("Value: " + i + " Class Label:" + example.classifyValue(i));
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Value: 0 Class Label:A
Value: 1 Class Label:A
Value: 2 Class Label:A
Value: 3 Class Label:A
Value: 4 Class Label:A
Value: 5 Class Label:A
Value: 6 Class Label:A
Value: 7 Class Label:A
Value: 8 Class Label:A
Value: 9 Class Label:A
Value: 10 Class Label:B
Value: 11 Class Label:B
Value: 12 Class Label:B
Value: 13 Class Label:B
Value: 14 Class Label:B
Value: 15 Class Label:B
Value: 16 Class Label:B
Value: 17 Class Label:B
Value: 18 Class Label:B
Value: 19 Class Label:B
```

Comment: I actually realised that my data was non-linear but I won't change the question. I dealt with this by using a support vector machine also supported by Weka. To do this just use  `Classifier cModel = (Classifier)new LibSVM();` Download LibSVM from here http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ and set the jar to your class path.